# armazennar o valor formatado da data do meu created_at na ID

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, migrations

Tenho uma dúvida:
Foi criada uma coluna chamada `shoe_id` na minha tabela, eu gostaria que essa `id` fosse gerada automaticamente quando eu cadastrasse um produto, e também gostaria que ela fosse no formato sem divisores a partir da data de criação, por exemplo:
o que eu quero implementar no Browser acontece quando no console eu faço

```
shoes =  Shoe.new(:shoe_id => shoes.created_at.to_formatted_s(:number))
shoes.save
```

como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

forma de fazer isso é utilizando [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) , onde na ação de criar do objeto (`after_create`), você vai setar esse valor para o campo `shoe_id`, dessa forma por exemplo:

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :generate_shoe_id

  def generate_shoe_id
    self.update(shoe_id: created_at.to_formatted_s(:number))
  end
end
```

Comment: Pensei em utilizar before_create e alterar a maneira de pegar a data de criação atual, como juntar o Time.now com o Data.now por exemplo, ou em últimos casos, ao invés de utilizar o to_formatted_s(:number), utilizar o .gsub(/\D/, ''), porém, acredito que na última linha ele terá que fazer o código da seguinte forma:

[lself.update(shoe_id: created_at.to_s.gsub(/\D/, ''))]

Acho que isso já pode ajudar a resolver o problema...